# How to build a sample project in gtk 3.0

Tags: c++, eclipse, gtk, eclipse-cdt

I just started to learn programming in C++ using eclipse cdt and gtk in Ubuntu.

The packages I was able to install and configure are:

1. Install gtk3.0
2. install pkg-config from the market place
3. Added ${PKCFLAGS} in Cross G++ Compiler
   Now: ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}${PKCFLAGS}
4. Added ${PKCFLAGS} in Cross G++ Linker
   Now: ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}${PKCFLAGS}

I tried to run a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int   argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init (&amp;amp;argc, &amp;amp;argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), &amp;quot;Window :-)&amp;quot;);

  g_signal_connect (window, &amp;quot;destroy&amp;quot;, G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

But I am still getting an error "Unresolved inclusion: "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems,

1. I needed to add also gtk+2.0 in C/C++ Build => settings
2. I did not noticed but there are several issues with the code I attached it's 
   with some strange symbols, I changed it to this:

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
   ```

   int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
         GtkWidget *window;

   ```
     gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

     window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
     gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello world");

     g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

     gtk_widget_show (window);

     gtk_main ();

     return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: I think he wants to use Gtk+-3.0 as he typed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal
`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
 and put the output in the "compiler flags" field somewhere in eclipse's settings.
Run 
`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
and put the output from this command in the "linker flags" field. Don't use cross compiler settings unless you are really cross compiling. This should compile as long as you code is right.